# Так вот, какой ты, гордый северный олень...

Tags: пунктуация

Написал эту фразу, а потом засомневался: а нужна ли тут запятая после "вот"? Подскажите, пожалуйста, а то знаки препинания - мое слабое место.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

ПРАВИЛЬНО: Так вот  какой ты, северный олень...

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ:

ТАК в знач. союза (или частицы) в начале  реплики:  следовательно, итак,  в таком случае. Все готово. - Т. едем? Т. согласен?

ВОТ  частица. В  сочетании с  местоименными  словами "какой",  "как"   и выражает  высокую  степень  оценки, удивления. В.  сколько орехов! В. в какую глушь заехали! В. как обрадовался!

СЕВЕРНЫЙ ОЛЕНЬ - обособленное приложение, отнесенное к личному местоимению (обособляется в любой позиции) или обращение риторического плана.